# Can't send GET request from Vue.js to CodeIgniter 3 backend

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, codeigniter

I am trying to send a `GET request` from my Vue app using `$http.get`. When I call the function that handles the req all I get in console is : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at X from origin Y has been blocked by cors policy`

Even though it is not safe I tried adding to my CI3 controller the following:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

Do I have to send headers from Vue ?

I must mention that I can access the link I am sending a get request to if I open it in browser or in PostMan

Vue.js code:

```
if(queryString !== '') {
                this.$http.get('LINK_HERE', {params: {q: queryString}})
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
            }
```

What am I missing? I really tried a lot of solutions but nothing helps, being a noob in Vue isn't helpful either.

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: LINK_HERE
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
```

RESPONSE HEADERS:

```
Content-Length: 366
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2020 14:46:13 GMT
Location: LINK_HERE/API_PATH
Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/5.6.35
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you add the php script that you are using, are you initializing the header at the start ?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, eliminate these two lines:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

You may want to add them back in once you get it working, but assuming there are no other influences (such as headers added by the web server itself), these are the most likely cause of the problem.

If that doesn't solve your problem, then you'll need to check your developer console to see all of the headers your request is sending and all of the headers your response is returning. Update your question with that information if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Deleting the lines didn't solve it. I updated the question.

Comment: Can you also post the response headers if you access the handler directly?

Comment: Oh, and actually you can see the problem. If those are your response headers, you can see that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not being set. This is most likely a configuration issue in your nginx where the server is clearing that header at the server level. It is not uncommon for this practice to ensure developers do not expose security issues.

Comment: how can I check this or even disable this behaviour ?

Comment: That can depend on your hosting environment. Is it a self-managed cloud, vps, or metal server? Or is it a shared hosting environment? Is there someone else who manages the server? Do you have terminal access to the server?

Comment: I use WAMPP, I can access all features on it since it is a dedicated server.

Comment: Is there an `.htaccess` file in the root of your web application (or any parent folders to the handler)?

Comment: Yes, there is a htacces files

Comment: Post the htaccess contents in your question please.

Comment: Can you also please post the relative path to the handler? You don't have to include your host, but something like `/path/to/handler`? Lastly, have you tried accessing the handler directly in your browser yet?

Comment: Yes, accessing it returns a JSON as expected. I have another API endpoint handled by another controller related to another app that uses Angular, there I get the correct response Headers.

Comment: Then you may need to post the entire handler. Something is clearing those headers. My only other guess is that your URL to the handler is off, which means your headers aren't going to get set and also could cause the CI engine to return something different.

Comment: I tried adding a location header. If I acces the route directy /controller/function I get redirected, but when I call the JS function nothing happens.

Comment: How is it that your Request headers don't include the parameters you are sending? Are you sure you're calling that `get` method correctly in your Vue code?

Answer (score 0):

try to set your XMLHttpRequest content type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
if you using axios then this is to config the header:

`axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`